# i wanna check if client name doesn't repeat but doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, api

```
  public function insertclients(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Clients();
    $client->client_name = $request->input('client_name');
    $client->client_society = $request->input('client_society');
    $client->client_email = $request->input('client_email');
    $client->client_address = $request->input('client_address');
    $client->client_phone = $request->input('client_phone');
    $client->client_fix = $request->input('client_fix');
    if ($this->nameclient($request->input('client_name')) < 1) {
        $client->save();
        return response()->json($client);
    } else {
        return response()->json('error', 'Client name already exists');        }
    // return redirect('clients')->with('flash_message', 'Client Addedd!');
}
public function nameclient(Request $request)
{
    //check count of client name
    $count = Clients::where('client_name', $request->input('client_name'))->get();
    $clicount = $count->count();
    return $clicount;
}
```

I have this method for add new client but i wanna check if the name don't repeat so i create other function who check the name of client and i call it in the ferst but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending the input with `$this->nameclient($request->input('client_name')`

so change your method to accept a string variable

```
public function nameclient($clientName)
{
    return Clients::where('client_name', $clientName)->count();
}
```

Bonus:

Maybe this way it would be more readable

```
public function insertclients(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->nameclient($request->input('client_name')) {
        return response()->json('error', 'Client name already exists');
    }

    $client = new Clients();
    $client->client_name = $request->input('client_name');
    $client->client_society = $request->input('client_society');
    $client->client_email = $request->input('client_email');
    $client->client_address = $request->input('client_address');
    $client->client_phone = $request->input('client_phone');
    $client->client_fix = $request->input('client_fix');
    $client->save();
    return response()->json($client);
    // return redirect('clients')->with('flash_message', 'Client Addedd!');
}
```

You can also use laravel Validation instead of using the method `nameclient` and add the other validation rules in it like required fields and such.

```
public function insertclients(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'client_name' => 'required|unique:clients|max:255',
    ]);


    $client = new Clients();
    $client->client_name = $request->input('client_name');
    $client->client_society = $request->input('client_society');
    $client->client_email = $request->input('client_email');
    $client->client_address = $request->input('client_address');
    $client->client_phone = $request->input('client_phone');
    $client->client_fix = $request->input('client_fix');
    $client->save();
    return response()->json($client);
    // return redirect('clients')->with('flash_message', 'Client Addedd!');
}
```

Comment: actually this method already work the problem in insert function doesn't work

Comment: @userdou what error are you getting? how did you know that the `save()` did not work ? did you check `dd($client)` after `$client->save();` and verified that no `id` was set ?